# Using the google ad manager api to delete a line item

Tags: google-api, google-ads-api, google-ad-manager

I need some help with the google ad manager API. I am trying to delete a `lineitem` with the following:

```
from googleads import ad_manager
client = ad_manager.AdManagerClient.LoadFromStorage()

def test(id):
    line_item_service = client.GetService('LineItemService',version='v202002')
    line_item_name = str(id)
    statement = (ad_manager.StatementBuilder(version='v202002').Where('OrderId = :OrderId').WithBindVariable('OrderId',app.config['AD_MANAGER']['ORDER_ID']))
   
    response = line_item_service.performLineItemAction(line_item_service.DeleteLineItems(),statement.ToStatement())
```

My problem lies with `DeleteLineItems()` as I am not sure how to call it correctly. I am not able to find clear usage examples, hence my attempt above. Below are the docs I could find. The error of my current attempt is:

```
{success: false, error: "<class 'googleads.errors.GoogleAdsValueError'>", message: "Service DeleteLineItems not found"}
```

https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/api/reference/v202011/LineItemService.DeleteLineItems
https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/api/reference/v202011/LineItemService#performLineItemAction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally found the answer.

The `performLineItemAction` takes in 2 parameters. The first one is the `LineItemAction` and the second is a `Statement`. I found the docs a little confusing because I thought the `LineItemAction` was a method of the `LineItem` object. It turns out that the first parameter is actually a dictionary.

```
line_item_service.performLineItemAction({'xsi_type':'ArchiveLineItems'},statement.ToStatement())
```

As a side note, once a line item is being delivered we cannot delete it. We can either pause it or archive it. In this case I've chosen to archive it. The different types of line item actions can be found here.

https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/api/reference/v202011/LineItemService#performLineItemAction

Comment: Hey Mark, your answer says we cannot delete it but in the link you’re shared there exist a ‘DeleteLineItem’ LineItemAction type. Was it not there back when you were looking for a solution?